# SQL Server Lost Execution Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database runs OLTP constantly. About once a week (sometimes more, sometimes less), one stored procedure brings the whole database server to a halt via CPU consumption. I alleviate the issue by recompiling the stored procedure. This is no longer a viable solution and need assistance in identifying the cause and a solution. Any guidance would be appreciated. My Our assumption is that a “good” execution plan is being lost and replaced with a “bad” execution plan.

Comment: Could you add the details of the "one stored procedure", code, execution plan, something with a little more detail?

Comment: You might have better luck at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

> Our assumption is that a “good” execution plan is being lost and replaced with a “bad” execution plan.

More likely is that a "good" execution at one time is now a "bad" plan with the current set of data.

Some things that may help:

- Make sure statistics are up-to-date (daily if not more frequent)
- Perform routine (daily) maintenance to reduce fragmentation

You don't say why recompiling is not a viable option but that could be helpful as well.

All of this can be automated so you don't have to babysit the system.